# css HTML gallery react to keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard

I recently made a rudimentary html/css galery that is practicaly a table with next/previous buttons.The thing is I want to make it responsive to keyboard.Like if anyone hits the "left" button on keyboard it should go on the previous photo and if it hits the "right" button go on the next page.
I would love if you could make it with as less javascript/jquery as possible.I searched google for something like that but I haven't found none !
If you need any code of my website please let me know.
Please help !

Comment: yes code of your website

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the keyboard interaction using `.on()` and the `keydown` *event*, and decide what to do after the returned value like :

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    console.log(code)
    if (code == 40) {
        // down arrow pressed : do something
        console.log("down arrow pressed")
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4gmsp65n/)**

The keyboard map of the navigation arrows are

```
// 37 = left arrow
// 38 = up arrow
// 39 = right arrow
// 40 = down arrow
```

**EDIT** : to avoid excessive use of `if` `else if` `else`, you could use `switch` (which performs better) like :

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    switch (code) {
        case 37:
            console.log("left arrow pressed")
            break;
        case 38:
            console.log("up arrow pressed")
            break;
        case 39:
            console.log("right arrow pressed")
            break;
        case 40:
            console.log("down arrow pressed")
            break;
        default:
            return false
    }
});
```

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4gmsp65n/2)**

Answer (score 0):

JFK's answer is correct, but I extended that a little

```
$(document).on("keydown", function (e) {
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (code == 40 || code == 39) { // down & right
        // replace selector with your button id/class
        $('.btn-next').click();
    } else if (code == 38 || code == 37) { // up & left
        // replace selector with your button id/class
        $('.btn-previous').click();
    }
});
```

The code simulates a click on the next/previous buttons so you are able to place any code which should happen when clicking or key pressing only once.

Comment: next should be `right`, not `down` ... you could have suggested this as a comment instead

Comment: No, since it is a different approach. Maybe he doesn't want to have this  behavior and wants to have custom code for key buttons then your answer is fitting more...

Comment: Don't see how come is a different approach since you are copying my answer into yours + some `if` `else` statements (which I covered with `switch`) ... whatever